# Register font with web URL in node canvas

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, node-canvas

I would like to use a canvas which loads a Google Font from a web URL on the nodejs server side.

I have used the following code:

```
registerfont("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v16/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6D6MmTpA.woff2",{ family: 'Pacifico' })
```

But I am getting a "path not found" error. Can we load `registerfont` with any web URL? I have successfully loaded local fonts that have been downloaded before. But is there any chance of loading them through web URLs?

Comment: There is no way to make it load a font via web URL, it has to be a local path. You'll need to load the font yourself and save it to the local filesystem before feeding it into the node-canvas.

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1527